# check multiple check box and display multiple details

Tags: php, mysql

Hi Can you help me what is the problem in this? 
if i check 1 checkbox it display details but when i choose to click two or more it displays blank. I dont understand if what is wrong in this code? is this correct? SELECT * FROM machine_and_equipments where MENo IN('$stk') or maybe have additional code to do?

```
<form action="CHECKBOX.php" method="post">
 <input type="hidden" name="color" value="0"/>
<?php

 include('function.php');
$name = isset($_POST['stick'])?$_POST['stick']:NULL; 
if(isset($_POST['stick'])){ 
    foreach ($name as $stk){            
//checkboxes
$stk = implode(',', $name);
//echo $stk;
$query = "SELECT * FROM machine_and_equipments where MENo IN('$stk')";  
$result = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());


    while($query_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $controlnumber = $query_row['MENo'];
    $assetname = $query_row['machine_equipments_name']; 
    $location = $query_row['Location'];    


?>
<br>
<table>
    <tr>
    <td>
        <?php echo $controlnumber;?>
    </td>
    <td>
        <?php echo $assetname;?>
    </td>
    <td>
        <?php echo $location;?>
    </td>
    </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<?php     }}}
?>
KMP-AC1-001<input type="checkbox" name="stick[]" id="stick" value="KMP-AC1-001"><br />
KMP-AC2-002<input type="checkbox" name="stick[]" id="stick" value="KMP-AC2-002"><br />
KMP-AC3-003<input type="checkbox" name="stick[]" id="stick" value="KMP-AC3-003"><br />
KMP-AC4-004<input type="checkbox" name="stick[]" id="stick" value="KMP-AC4-004"><br />
KMP-RF1-005<input type="checkbox" name="stick[]" id="stick" value="KMP-RF1-005"><br />
KMP-RF2-006<input type="checkbox" name="stick[]" id="stick" value="KMP-RF2-006"><br />
KMP-EL2-009<input type="checkbox" name="stick[]" id="stick" value="KMP-EL2-009"><br />
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: turn on error reporting and remove these `id="stick"` because they are supposed to be unique!

Comment: Note: The `mysql_*` function are deprecated and will be removed from future versions of PHP. Your code will stop working then. You should use `mysqli_*` or PDO instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify the following lines:

```
$stk = "'" . implode("','", $name) . "'"; 
//echo $stk;
$query = "SELECT * FROM machine_and_equipments where MENo IN($stk)";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   <form action="CHECKBOX.php" method="post">
 <input type="hidden" name="color" value="0"/>
<?php

 include('function.php');
$name = isset($_POST['stick'])?$_POST['stick']:NULL; 
if(isset($_POST['stick'])){ 

//checkboxes
$stk = "'" . implode("','", $name) . "'"; 
echo $stk;
$query = "SELECT * FROM machine_and_equipments where MENo IN($stk)";  
$result = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());


    while($query_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $controlnumber = $query_row['MENo'];
    $assetname = $query_row['machine_equipments_name']; 
    $location = $query_row['Location'];    


?>
<br>
<table>
    <tr>
    <td>
        <?php echo $controlnumber;?>
    </td>
    <td>
        <?php echo $assetname;?>
    </td>
    <td>
        <?php echo $location;?>
    </td>
    </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<?php     }}

?>


KMP-AC1-001<input type="checkbox" name="stick[]" id="stick" value="KMP-AC1-001"><br />
KMP-AC2-002<input type="checkbox" name="stick[]" id="stick" value="KMP-AC2-002"><br />
KMP-AC3-003<input type="checkbox" name="stick[]" id="stick" value="KMP-AC3-003"><br />
KMP-AC4-004<input type="checkbox" name="stick[]" id="stick" value="KMP-AC4-004"><br />
KMP-RF1-005<input type="checkbox" name="stick[]" id="stick" value="KMP-RF1-005"><br />
KMP-RF2-006<input type="checkbox" name="stick[]" id="stick" value="KMP-RF2-006"><br />
KMP-EL2-009<input type="checkbox" name="stick[]" id="stick" value="KMP-EL2-009"><br />
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```